# Closing off heating ducts

Tags: furnace

We have a natural gas furnace that currently heats our entire 2400 square foot home. We plan on putting in a rental suite in the basement which will require closing up all the duct work into the suite space. That means that the furnace will be heating up 36% less space. Is there anything we can do to keep our furnace from self-destructing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that your furnace will self-destruct if you don't run it as much, but it's not going to.

Unless the second unit is insulated, you'll probably just end up heating it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could have someone come out and rebalance your furnace ducts to compensate for the lower airflow.

However, if you are in the (very common) position of thinking that closing off ducts "strains your furnace blower" you happen to have it exactly backwards (and you have lots of company) - closing off ducts in fact reduces the load on your furnace blower (and opening them up increases it.) Counterintuitive but true.

So your furnace should not be self-destructing, even if you don't have it rebalanced.

Some time in the past I posted another answer about this with references.

Comment: can you add a link to your previous answer? Thanks.

Comment: Can't seem to find it now. Look at figure 3 here http://www.greenheck.com/library/articles/10 and note that as pressure is lowered and flow increases, horsepower increases (and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely to short cycle from over-heating due to insufficient airflow. Overheating will contribute to premature over-temp limit switch failure. Short cycling puts a *little* more hurt on everything that has to start and stop. I wouldn't worry unless you notice it acting funny; cannot reach set temp, continually starts and stops (keeps reigniting) before reaching set temp.

A solution would be to manually vary the gas value; **cut the gas back** some. Short cycles will happen less and the furnace will put out a properly downsized amount of BTU's. Watch the flame through the little window while you play with the valve (not to much, I doubt your basement required 36% of your furnace's output).

---

Anecdote:

You have a very airtight home if a single furnace can heat your 2400sf. A house that size borderline requires dual split systems anyway. I lived in a 1700sf apartment that had a 150k BTU furnace which could barely keep up. I think your furnace will actually like this change and will *certainly* need to run less once someone is heating the basement for you.

---

Unsolicited advice:

It would be best to disconnect the runs from the plenum chamber, instead of just capping them at their end points (where the tenant might also decide to uncap them) for greater efficiency.

Bear in mind that you will need access to your unit and the tenant needs access to their breaker panel. Also, the suite itself needs two means of egress, as do any bedrooms (windows with a [minimum net clear opening of 5.7 sq](http://www.homesafetysolutionsinc.com/page/page/4282797.htm) count as one).

Comment: Depending on your furnace, you may be able to install a smaller burner, or smaller orifices, to reduce the heat output, if needed.   Rather than guessing, I'd have a pro evaluate your system to determine how many BTUs it should produce and help with any duct rebalancing that may be needed.